# ¿Cómo instanciar servicios wcf diferentes desde una clase común?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, wcf

tengo un servicio WCF instalado en un servidor y otro exactamente igual instalado en otro servidor.
En una aplicación tengo que consumir ambos. Los referencio de la siguiente manera:

```
MiAplicacion.MiReferenciaServ_1.MiServicio servicio1 = new MiAplicacion.MiReferenciaServ_1.MiServicio();
MiAplicacion.MiReferenciaServ_2.MiServicio servicio2 = new MiAplicacion.MiReferenciaServ_2.MiServicio();
```

Lo que necesito es una clase `GetServicio(int param)` que si le paso el valor 1, por ejemplo, me devuelva una instancia al servicio1 y si le paso el valor 2 me devuelva una instancia al servicio2.

Comment: Los dos servicios son idénticos. Uno está en un servidor y apunta a una bbdd y el otro hace lo mismo en otro servidor. La unica diferencia es la querystring del archivo de configuración.

Comment: Sí. La única diferencia es el nombre que se le asigna en la aplicación al referenciarlo.

Comment: El problema es complejo la verdad. Como una solución rápida, puedes hacer que tu método `GetServicio` devuelva como tipo `dynamic`, lo que hará que el tipo se determine en tiempo de ejecución. Luego, tal vez tengas que tener cuidado con el tipo que estas usando, pero depende de tu implementación.

Comment: La verdad es que le he estado dando vueltas y no he sido capaz. También lo he intentado con los genéricos y nada. Tal vez simplemente no se pueda hacer.

Comment: Carlos, yo he hecho una prueba usando `dynamic` y funciona correctamente. Simplemente, define tu método asi `static dynamic GetServicio(){...}` y dentro devuelve la instancia  que te interese, y lo llamas asi: `var cliente1 = GetServicio();`. No es ni mucho menos lo ideal, pero es que lo normal es que usar una referencia unica. Otra opción sería usar factorias probablemente, pero es mas complejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pikoh, he probado como dices y funciona.
Pongo el código de ejemplo por si a alguien más le sirve:

```
//Esta es la clase a la que le quiero solicitar el servicio a utilizar
public class Servicios()
{
   public static dynamic GetServicio(int param)
   {
       //Declaración del servicio, una para cada servidor.
       PruebaServ.MiReferenciaServ_1.MiServicioClient servicio1 = new MiReferenciaServ_1.MiServicioClient();
       PruebaServ.MiReferenciaServ_2.MiServicioClient servicio2 = new MiReferenciaServ_2.MiServicioClient();

       if (param == 2)
          return servicio2;
       else
          return servicio1;
   } 
}

//Este método está en el formulario desde donde quiero consumir el servicio.
//El servicio implementa un contrato GetFecha() de prueba que devuelve la fecha actual
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var miServicio = Servicios.GetServicio(1);
   //Aquí consumo el contrato del servicio
   var fechahoy = miServicio.GetFecha();
   //¡¡ el problema es que el intelillense no me muestra los contratos del servicio
}
```

El problema es que pierdo el intelillense de visual studio y el servicio real publica más de 100 contratos.

¿Alguna forma de tener el intelillense al consumir el servicio?

Comment: No. Como te dije, esta solución es un poco "chapuza". Al usar dynamic, el tipo de la variable solo es conocido en tiempo de ejecución, con lo que Visual Studio obviamente no lo conoce y no puede darte información de la clase mediante Intellisense. Para que te funcionase,deberias hacer un cast al tipo correcto, pero en ese caso estarías en las mismas. Por cierto, no uses la respuesta para repreguntar, hazlo en un comentario mejor.

Comment: De todas maneras, viendo tu código...no te merece mas la pena crear ambos objetos, y discriminar cual usar mediante el parámetro? es decir, algo como `if (param==1) {miServicio.GetFecha();} else {miServicio2.GetFecha();}`

Comment: Así es como lo tengo ahora, pero es un follón porque tengo que repetir mucho código, además de la inicialización del servicio está el paso de parámetros, los objetos que el servicio proporciona, etc. de manera que tengo que duplicar un montón de código.